# How to replace symbol AND make next letter uppercase in Go

Tags: regex, string, go

I'm beginner trainee in Go.
I can't figure out how not just replace a symbol, but to make next letter Uppercase in Go.

Task:
Complete the method/function so that it converts dash/underscore delimited words into camel casing. The first word within the output should be capitalized only if the original word was capitalized (known as Upper Camel Case, also often referred to as Pascal case).

I tried to implement regexp methods with:

```
re, _ := regexp.Compile(`/[-_]\w/ig`)
    res := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(s, -1)
return res
```

But i can't return res because it's slice/array, but i need to return just string.

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func ToCamelCase(s string) string {
    s = strings.ReplaceAll(s, "-", "")
    s = strings.ReplaceAll(s, "_", "")
    return s
}

func main() {
    var s string
    fmt.Scan(&s)
    fmt.Println(ToCamelCase(s))
}
```

Input:
"the-stealth-warrior" or "the_stealth_warrior"

Output:
"theStealthWarrior" or "TheStealthWarrior"

My Output: thestealthwarrior

Comment: Do not use regex delimiters when defining regex with string literals in Go.

Comment: Why people downwoting me?

Comment: Probably due to the regex delimiters. It catches the eye at once, and most people think it is a typo question, though there is another problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the regex without regex delimiters in Go string literals, and it is more convenient to use the [`ReplaceAllStringFunc` function](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.ReplaceAllStringFunc):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func ToCamelCase(s string) string {
    re, _ := regexp.Compile(`[-_]\w`)
    res := re.ReplaceAllStringFunc(s, func(m string) string {
        return strings.ToUpper(m[1:])
    })
    return res
}

func main() {
    s := "the-stealth-warrior"
    fmt.Println(ToCamelCase(s))
}
```

See the [Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/2sONVelCRsp).

The output is `theStealthWarrior`.

The `[-_]\w` pattern matches a `-` or `_` and then any word char. If you want to exclude `_` from `\w`, use `[^\W_]` instead of `\w`.